# How to find Xpath?

Tags: xpath

is there any easy way to find xpath ?

```
<span class="r5">5</span><a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

what will be the xpath of r5 ?

Thanks..

Comment: See [How to calculate the XPath position of an element using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454526/how-to-calculate-the-xpath-position-of-an-element-using-javascript/3454545#3454545).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`span[@class='r5']`