# Can Selenium support to get "XPath/Dom" and more info from a dynamically generated web page?

Tags: dom, xpath, selenium

I have searched several questions but I didn't figure out my problem:

I want to test/verify configuration pages of 2 systems.  But I faced 3 challenges:

1.The pages for 2 systems look same at all, but actually the dom/xPath info of same items(text,drop-down list, radio button and so on) are totally different.  For example, the "Device Name" fields of 2 systems on the page have 2 different xPath, such as xPath of sys1 is "//input/abc" and xPath of sys2 is "//input/xyz".

2.Sometimes the page is generated dynamically so the dom/xPath of the same item of one system may be different at different time.

3.Based on 1 & 2, it's difficult of me to write one script to run on all systems(we'll have more system in the future).  I don't want to define different xpath/dom database for different systems.

My question is:

1.Can selenium return how many “text field" "drop-down list" "radio button" objects on the page?

2.Can selenium return xPath/dom of each objects in Question1?

I hope selenium can return all objects and xPath/dom info of each object, so that I can make a mapping and call for different systems(I can decide which xPath is currently using by comparing the Index/Location of "same" objects).

Appreciate for all comments/help.

Comment: Are you using selenium 1 or Selenium 2?

Comment: If anyone can tell me how to get all objects and the xPath/dom/css of these objects thru JS or other ways, that would be OK too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know c#, but for Java there is a driver.findElements(By.xpath/css(xpath/css value))). This will return you the number of elements in the page. If its a textbox that you have to find you can use something like

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(//input[@type='textbox']).size();
```

This will return the number of textboxes in the page.

For question 2 - Check this. There was a similar question asked in SO.

[How to calculate the XPath position of an element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454526/how-to-calculate-the-xpath-position-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks.  If the page contains 10 textbox, 5 drop-down list.  Do you know how to get the xpath of each of them?  I need to make a mapping of each object and its xpath/dom/css or something that Selenium can handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq for something like this. For example, getting all input elements can be done via:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
var inputElements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("input")); // get all input elements
inputElements.Count(); // get how many input elements there are
```

or:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
var inputElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input")); // get all input elements
inputElements.Count(); // get how many input elements there are
```

Comment: Arran, thanks!  How to find out the xpath/dom info for each object ?