# jquery : create xpath of the current text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

Is there a way, using jquery to get an XPath query of the current text selection?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the XPath position of an element using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454526/how-to-calculate-the-xpath-position-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

*Updated* It should work now:

```
var path = "/" + element.parents().map(function () {
    return this.tagName;
}).get().reverse().join("/");

path += "/" + element.prop("tagName") + "[" + (element.prevAll().length + 1) + "]";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/95PnT/5/

Comment: This is not good enough. If there are multiple siblings at a level with the same tag name, you don't know which one to choose.

Comment: it gets the parents of an element at first step: $(element).parents()

Comment: @alijsh: Yes, so it generators something like `a/b/c`. What if `a` has two `b` children? How do you know which one to select when you are trying to apply the XPath? You have to consider this information as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in method to do this using jQuery.
There are, however, other javascript options, see here: [How to calculate the XPath position of an element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454526/how-to-calculate-the-xpath-position-of-an-element-using-javascript)