# Front-end Visual XPath Identification

Tags: javascript, ruby, xpath, rubygems, frontend

I am looking for JS or Ruby library which allows me visually (user front-end) select page elements and identify theirs XPath for further use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate XPath for element in JavaScript check: [How to calculate the XPath position of an element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454526/how-to-calculate-the-xpath-position-of-an-element-using-javascript). Also check this: [How to calculate the XPath position of an element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854936/jquery-create-xpath-of-the-current-text-selection).

Since Ruby is not "front-end language", I can't imagine how could it be useful here. But if you want to pick element for specific XPath check [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html).