# How to use xpath in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

To access an element i used the following command    `document.getElementById('ghi').innerHTML="Replace the paragragh with this text"` 
How to use the same functionality in javascript by using xpath As in out suite we used xpath only

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32623171/502860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would do what you want:

```
function xpathFindById(id) {
    return document.evaluate(".//*[@id='" + id + "']", document.lastChild, null,
                    XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
}

var content = xpathFindById("content");
```