# Finding a parent element in webdriver.io

Tags: webdriver-io

I've seen a couple of solutions in the original webdriver that use getAttribute('xpath') and append to that '/..' but webdriver.io doesn't have an xpath attribute so I haven't been able to use that. Any ideas on how to grab the parent element?

The case I am trying to test is inside of a bootstrap layout and the element that is actually getting the class I am trying to check is one above. It looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
  <other stuff>
</div>
```

I am selecting by driver.element("input[name='username'"] but the error class actually hits the div

```
<div class="form-group error">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
  <other stuff>
</div>
```

So I need to check if the div itself has an error class, not the input I can find (there are no uniques on the div)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just searched the same and found this by inspecting Webdriver.IO [source code](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/5471794/lib/helpers/findElementStrategy.js#L136) - you can use `el.$('..')` to get the parent element, like this:

```
$('input[name="username"]').$('..') // returns the parent element
```

Voila! It's a part of their XPath selectors support.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by using execute to get the xpath from jQuery, here is the code I used (albeit for a different test I was writing - if every label that has a * is a required field). Hopefully this is helpful to somebody in the future:

```
var requiredXPaths = browser.execute(function () {
var returner = [];
var $elements = $('.modal.fade.in').find("label:contains('*')");
  _.each($elements, el => {
    var xpath = '';
    var element = el.parentElement;
    for (; element && element.nodeType == 1; element = element.parentNode) {
      var id = $(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1;
      id > 1 ? (id = '[' + id + ']') : (id = '');
      xpath = '/' + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + xpath;
    }

    returner.push(xpath);
  });
  return returner;
});
```

I got the xPath function from another stackoverflow page ([How to calculate the XPath position of an element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454526/how-to-calculate-the-xpath-position-of-an-element-using-javascript))

Answer (score 0):

WebdriverIO actually lets you [use XPath in your selectors](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html#xPath), so any valid Xpath selector should work to find the element you want.

Alternatively, you could just use [isExisting](http://webdriver.io/api/state/isExisting.html) to check if the element exists on the page using the error class parent:

```
driver.isExisting('.error input[name="username"]');
```

If the element doesn't exist, then your error class didn't get added.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to hard-code the xpath of the element because it makes the tests fragile.

Answer (score 0):

I've been talking about this in gitter, when the parent can be selected `input[name="username"]`

The parent of this element can be selected as `//div[input[name="username"]]`